# Reading doubles in a file

Tags: java, for-loop, file-io, readfile

For my assignment I am to write a file that uses an input of trials to determine an average for a person winning a prize by opening a soda cap and looking if they won. They have a 1 in 5 chance to win. Once I have the averages for the separate trials, I am to read the trials back and calculate the average. I am having troubles trying to read the doubles from the file. This is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class BottleCapPrize
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  double averageBottles = 0.0;
  double randNum = 0.0;
  int bottleSum = 0;
  int numBottles = 1;
  int bottle = 0;
  int maxRange = 6;
  int minRange = 1;
  int oneTrial = 0;
  int winPrize = 1;
  double token = 0;
  int totalSumCaps = 0;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  //Generates bottle number for first test
  randNum = Math.random();
  bottle = ((int)((randNum) * (maxRange - minRange)) + minRange);

  //construct an object called outFile to allow access to output methods of the PrintWriter class  
  PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("trials.txt"));

  //Gets users input for how many trials
  System.out.print("Enter the amount of trials: ");
  int trials = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println();

  //Check averages for entered trials
   for (int loop = 1; loop <= trials; loop++)    
  {
      //Clears out the loops variables each time through
     if(loop != 0)
    {
         averageBottles = 0;
         bottleSum = 0;
         oneTrial = 0;
         numBottles = 0;
    }
     for(int x = 1; x <= 20; x++)
    {
       if(x == 20) //One trial is completed
      {
       averageBottles = bottleSum / x;
       //Replaces the old bottle number for a new bottle
        randNum = Math.random();
        bottle = ((int)((randNum) * (maxRange - minRange)) + minRange);
      }
      else if(bottle == winPrize)
      {
        oneTrial = numBottles;
        if(oneTrial == 0)
        {
            oneTrial = 1;
        }
        //Replaces the old bottle number for a new bottle
        randNum = Math.random();
        bottle = ((int)((randNum) * (maxRange - minRange)) + minRange);
      }
      else if(bottle != winPrize) //not a winner, gets new bottle and increments the number of bottles tested
      {
       //Replaces the old bottle number for a new bottle
       randNum = Math.random();
       bottle = ((int)((randNum) * (maxRange - minRange)) + minRange);
       oneTrial = numBottles;
       numBottles ++;
      }
      bottleSum += oneTrial; //Adds the sum from each trial
    }
     outFile.println("Trial " + loop + "." + " " + averageBottles); //Prints the averages to the file
     System.out.println("Trial " + loop + "." + " " + averageBottles);
     //outFile.println("Trial " + "=" + " " + averageBottles); //Prints the averages to the file
     //System.out.println("Trial "+ "=" + " " + " " + averageBottles);
  }//end of for loop
  outFile.close ( );//close the file when finished 

  //Read the trial data back in and calculate the average
  File fileName = new File("trials.txt");
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);

  //read file and get data
  while(inFile.hasNext())
  {
     token = inFile.nextDouble();
     totalSumCaps += token;
  }
  inFile.close();

  double totalAverageCaps = totalSumCaps / trials;
  //Print results
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("The average number of caps opened in order to win a prize is: " + totalAverageCaps);
}
```

}

Comment: see [`Double.parseDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

Comment: what do you mean by "having trouble"? what is going wrong?

Comment: You do know ints/doubles default to 0/0.0 right?

Comment: So what is nextDouble("Trial 123.0.65739") going to give you? My guess would be not a double....

Comment: When the program reaches token = inFile.nextDouble(); it produces this "java.util.InputMismatchException: null(in java.util.Scanner) @Epicblood

Comment: So how do I get it to just read the double portion of the "Trial = 7.0)" @TonyHopkinson

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to read in a `String` and convert it to a `double`, then all you need to do is use `next()` from `Scanner`, which returns a `String`.  Then you can use `Double.parseDouble(String s)` to convert your `String` to a `double`.  Or you could use `nextDouble()` from `Scanner`.

Not sure if you've learned exception handling yet, but if so, you can use a `try-catch` block to catch a possible `NumberFormatException`.  Also, if you've learned methods, you should use them, ie you should have as little code as possible in your main.  You can use methods to make your code a lot cleaner.

EDIT:
You're getting an `InputMismatchException` from `nextDouble()` because the token that you're reading is not a `double`.

Comment: I just took out the string part of the file and left the double part and that worked, thank you!